# How do I use a models current id to query another model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two classes, `JobFinancialInfo(models.Model)` and another model class with a field called `financial_info = models.OneToOneField(JobFinancialInfo, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`. I'm trying to create an @property on JobFinancialInfo that will return all of the objects from the second model that has the id of self.id(?) of JobFinancialInfo. I want to do this specifically so I can run an aggregation on another field in the second models as a property on the first. Is there a way to do this, or is there a better, more efficient way?

Comment: There is at most *one* such object, that is why it is a `OneToOneField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a `@property` on  `JobFinancialInfo` that will return all of the objects from the second model that has the id of `self.id` of `JobFinancialInfo`.

Since it is a `OneToOneField`, there is *at most* one such object. Indeed, a `OneToOneField` is in essence a `ForeignKey` that is `unique=True`, so that means there can not be two models that refer to the same object.

If you however make a `OneToOneField`, Django will *automatically* construct a relation in reverse, so that means that if the other model is named `OtherModel`, you can access the `OtherModel` that refers to that `JobFinancialInfo` object with:

```
myjobfinancialinfo.othermodel
```

This will raise an `OtherModel.DoesNotExist` exception if there is no such element.

So you can try to find it with:

```
try:
    myjobfinancialinfo.othermodel
except OtherModel.DoesNotExist:
    # … do something …
    pass
```

You can use a *many-to-one* relation with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), in that case multiple `OtherModel`s can link to the *same* `JobFinancialInfo`. In that case you can retrieve the items with:

```
myjobfinancialinfo.othermodel_set.all()
```

This can be an `QuerySet` that contains zero, one, or more elements.

If you do not want to use `othermodel`, or `othermodel_set`, you can alter the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), to specify another name.

For example if the `OtherModel` looks like:

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):
    financial_info = models.ForeignKey(
        JobFinancialInfo,
        related_name='othermodels'
    )
```

then you access the related objects with:

```
myjobfinancialinfo.othermodels.all()
```

Comment: It sounds like I might need to make a many to one relationship – does that change the automatic reverse relation construction? p.s. thank you!!

Comment: @NovicePython127: yes, if you use a `ForeignKey`, then it means that there are many items that relate to the `JobFinancialInfo`, then you access it with `myjobfiancialinfo.othermodel_set.all()`.